# Need help get content view height - Android

Tags: java, android

I need some help to get my custom webView **CONTENT** height, please check below is my code

```
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final int displayHeight = webView.getHeight();
            final int contentRange = webView.getContentHeight();
            final int y = v.getScrollY();


            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    Log.d("Get webView height ", "" + displayHeight); // Result : 528
                    Log.d("Get webView content height ", "" + contentRange); // Result : 2112
                    Log.d("Get webView content scroll top ", "" + y);

                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            }

            return false;
        };
```

Above is my code to get my custom webView content height with webview.setOnTouchListener, that code is work.

But, now I want to get my custom WebView content height from button click, that does not work, what I got is always get a height of my webView not the content height, below my code for button click

```
Button btn = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnCLick);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int webViewContentHeight = webView.getContentHeight();

            Log.d("Get my custom webView content height", " " + webViewContentHeight); // Result : 528

        }
    });
```

Much appreciate if I can have a detailed procedure, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878069/android-get-height-of-webview-content-once-rendered

Comment: @user3698577 thanks for the comment, the code still give me result of webView height not content webView height :(

Comment: Are you sure that you fill your WebView before .getContentHeight? If there is no content, ContentHeight = WebView.Height

Comment: Hi @user3698577 hmmm I put my both code in  `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) { ...`, is that make a problem??? thank a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found to get contentHeight after rendering :

Create your own class extended WebView and this class in your layout :

```
public class BKWebView extends WebView {

private Activity yourActivity;

public BKWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public BKWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public BKWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void invalidate() {
    super.invalidate();

    if (getContentHeight() > 0) {
        // WebView has displayed some content and is scrollable.

        if (yourActivity != null)
            yourActivity.callBackWebView(getContentHeight());

    }
}

/**
 * @param yourActivity the yourActivity to set
 */
public void setYourActivity(Activity yourActivity) {
    this.yourActivity = yourActivity;
}
```

}

in your activity implement the callback method and then in your listener :

```
private webViewContentHeight;
BKWebView wv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    wv = (BKWebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);
    wv.setYourActivity(this);
    ...
}

public void callBackWebView(int contentHeight) {
    webViewContentHeight = contentHeight;
}


...
Button btn = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnCLick);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Get my custom webView content height", " " + webViewContentHeight); 
    }
});
...
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code, but I'm confuse what fjd is?? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi sorry I just back to my desk, yesterday was very busy, again thanks for your code, still I'm not understand what fjd is?? I use your code and android said can not resolve your symbol fjd on `if (fjd != null)
            fjd.callBackWebView(getContentHeight());

    }`, thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry, in BkWebView class I rename private var yourActivity, but I forgot to rename it inside the code. Code is now updated. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misunderstanding your question before. You can set the View and the Button global in the activity and instantiate it at `onCreate`. Make a separate `onClickEvent` for the button, not in `OnCreate`, where you call the global `WebView.getContentHeight()` this might work.

And in first case you could get things working right now with sending a click-event to the `WebView`. More dirty solution.

```
WebView.performClick();
```

Comment: Hmm, if the content never set, why when I used `webView.setOnTouchListener` to get my webView content height, it's work fine,  only when I use btn.setOnClickListener it doesn't work, any suggest ??thank for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript

```
String js = "javascript:function initialize() { "
            + "var d = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];"
            + "var visibleH = window.innerHeight; " 
            + "var fullH = d.offsetHeight; "
            + "jsInterface.jsGetContentHeight(visibleH ,fullH); " 
            + "}";  
wv.loadUrl(js);
wv.loadUrl("javascript:initialize()");
```

and then define JavaScriptInterface for webview to retrieve values

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(context),
            "jsInterface"); 
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void jsGetContentHeight(int visibleH,int fullH) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, visibleH +"-"+ fullH, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```