# Android: take screenshot of whole WebView in Nougat ( Android 7 )

Tags: android, webview, screenshot, android-7.0-nougat

I use below code to take screenshot from a `WebView`. it works well in Android 6 and lower versions but in Android 7 it takes only the visible part of the webview.

```
// before setContentView
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
        }
...
// before set webview url
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
// after html load complete
final Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                webView.getContentHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bitmapHolder = new Canvas(b);
        webView.draw(bitmapHolder);
```

but bitmap b is not complete. How can I take screenshot of whole `WebView` in Android Nougat?

Edit:
I found out the `webView.getContentHeight` doesn't works well. I hard coded the whole `webview` height and it works well. So the Question is : How can I get the Whole `WebView` Content Height in Android Nougat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following methods instead of getMeasuredWidth() & getContentHeight() method:

```
computeHorizontalScrollRange(); -> for width 
computeVerticalScrollRange(); -> for height
```

these two methods will return the entire scrollable width/height rather than the actual widht/height of the webview on screen

To achieve this you need to make WebViews   getMeasuredWidth() & getContentHeight() methods public like below

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView
{
    public MyWebView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollRange()
    {
        return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
    }

}
```

in other work around you can also use a view tree observer to calculate the webview height as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878558/3983054)

Comment: `computeVerticalScrollRange()` has protected access in `android.webkit.WebView`

Comment: is it helped for you ? @YaHoo

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below code block

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
    }
```

Disabling the entire HTML document has a significant performance cost.

As per the documentation,

> For apps targeting the L release, WebView has a new default behaviour that reduces memory footprint and increases performance by intelligently choosing the portion of the HTML document that needs to be drawn.

Might be worth looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454834/2700586)

Answer for Edit 1:
To retrieve the webview height after rendering
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878558/2700586

Comment: I comment it and try again but the problem happened again. this line is necessary for android L.

Comment: I have updated the answer please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/30223117/2700586

Comment: My problem is not in Android L. it is in Android N ( nougat, 7).

Comment: Same solution would be applicable for app targeting above L

Comment: I edited the question. the `webView.getContentHeight` doesn't works well. it returns the height of visible part.

Comment: Encouraging you to search the SO before questioning.